# Make a free space usable in Vista

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, partitioning, ntfs

I've just re-installed Vista, in my previously dual-booted system. Vista is installed on a 120 GB partition on my 250GB HDD. My HDD's architecture is as follows

- 120GB NTFS where `Vista` is installed
- 120GB extended, where `ubuntu` is installed(8GB swap, 25GB `\home` and 25GB `\`) along with the 60GB NTFS free space
- 3.5GB NTFS

I used Vista's Disk Management to make the free space, a new volume so as to use it. When I try to do so, however, I get a message that

> There is not enough space in disk(s) to perform this operation

I also tried to delete the free partition but I keep getting the same message. A screenshot from disk management, follows

[image: Disk management]

What can be done to use this free space?

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of disk management are very buggy, and often display logical partitions incorrectly. For example in your screenshot the extended partition contains only the "free space" along with 4 other primary partitions. That means there are 5 partitions in your MBR disk which is impossible on MBR. I've also seen that bug so many times in various different PCs. Diskmgmt.msc also has very limited partitioning capability compared to 3<sup>rd</sup> party solutions

So you'd better use some other partitioners such as [MiniTool® Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/convert-gpt-mbr-disk.html) or [EaseUS® Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) to resize the partitions. They're all much better than windows diskmgmt.msc. [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is also good if you're using Linux or has a USB pen drive to boot from